# How to center align everything in JPanels having GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, grid-layout

Recently,I had [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588490/how-do-i-arrange-jpanels-from-top-to-bottom/27588697#27588697) about how to make `JPanel`s align from top to bottom in a `JFrame`. Users told me to use `GridLayout()`. I got everything working,but I forgot to mention that I wanted to center align all the components in the `JPanel`s.

My first `JPanel` has a `JLabel`.
My second `JPanel` has 5 `JRadioButton`s.
My third `JPanel` has a `JLabel`.
My fourth `JPanel` has a `JButton`.

Selecting any `JRadioButton` would change the text of the `JLabel` in the third `JPanel`.When the program starts,the `JLabel` has no text.

My `JFrame` has `GridLayout`. All 4 `JPanel`s which have `BoxLayout`(`BoxLayout.X_Axis`) are added into this `JFrame`.Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  JPanel pan1,pan2,pan3,pan4;                   //4 JPanels
  JRadioButton rad1,rad2,rad3,rad4,rad5;   //5 RadioButtons
  JButton button;                          //A JButton
  JLabel label;                            //A JLabel
   public GUI(String header)
   {
      super(header);

      setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,6));  //set GridLayout to JFrame
      setBounds(350,325,600,125);
      setResizable(false);

      creator();
      adder();
      commander();

      add(pan1);
      add(pan2);
      add(pan3);
      add(pan4)  //Add all 4 panels to JFrame

  }


  private void adder()
  {
    pan1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan1,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    pan2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan2,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    pan3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan3,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    pan4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan4,BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); //Layout for all 4 JPanels

    pan1.add(new JLabel("Choose a Security Level"));

    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();

    group.add(rad1);
    group.add(rad2);
    group.add(rad3);
    group.add(rad4);
    group.add(rad5);

    pan2.add(rad1);
    pan2.add(rad2);
    pan2.add(rad3);
    pan2.add(rad4);
    pan2.add(rad5);

    pan3.add(label);

    pan4.add(button);
  }

   private void creator()
   {
      pan1=new JPanel();
      pan2=new JPanel();
      pan3=new JPanel();
      pan4=new JPanel();

      rad1=new JRadioButton("Security Level 1");
      rad2=new JRadioButton("Security Level 2");
      rad3=new JRadioButton("Security Level 3");
      rad4=new JRadioButton("Security Level 4");
      rad5=new JRadioButton("Security Level 5"); 

      button=new JButton("Move On");

      label=new JLabel();
   }

   private void commander()
   {
    rad1.addActionListener(this);
    rad2.addActionListener(this);
    rad3.addActionListener(this);
    rad4.addActionListener(this);
    rad5.addActionListener(this);

    rad1.setActionCommand("radio1");
    rad2.setActionCommand("radio2");
    rad3.setActionCommand("radio3");
    rad4.setActionCommand("radio4");
    rad5.setActionCommand("radio5");

    button.addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
   {
   //When button is pressed,the text in label changes

   if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("radio1"))
      label.setText("Very Easy to bypass");
    else if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("radio2"))
      label.setText("Easy to bypass");
    else if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("radio3"))
      label.setText("Can bypass Sometimes");
    else if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("radio4"))
      label.setText("Hard to bypass");
    else if(evt.getActionCommand().equals("radio5"))
      label.setText("Very Hard to bypass");
    else
    { //Code here
    }

    repaint();
    //More code here....
   }


}
```

And this is the output that I get(Ignore the green lines):
[image: My program]

I want everything to be aligned in the center rather than in the left. What should I do in order to align it?

Comment: BTW - `setBounds(350,325,600,125);` should be changed to `setLocationByPlatform(true); pack();` and those should be called after all content is added but before `setVisible(true);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson ,In my original code,I call `setBounds` and `setVisible` after I do `GUI prog=new GUI();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
pan1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan1,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

To something like:

```
pan1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

..And the same with the rest of the box layouts.

Comment: Now I think:Why hadn't I thought of that earlier? BTW,`FlowLayout.CENTER` isn't needed,is it?

Comment: *"..isn't needed,is it?"*  I've been leery of accepting defaults ever since Sun change the default layout of a frame from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` (a long time ago).

Comment: For a "row" with one element (such as the area containing the "Move On" button at the bottom of the screen), the `FlowLayout.Center` parameter is absolutely needed